# Template version of std::abs

Tags: c++, templates, cmath

[Here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/fabs) lists the current overloads of `std::abs` in C++. I'm wondering why not just define the following template and let go all the ugly C-style overloads?

```
template <typename T> inline
T abs(const T& v) { return v < 0 ? -v : v; }
```

Comment: And what is `abs<string>` or `abs<foo*>`?

Comment: @MariusBancila Then it won't compile for non-compatible types.

Comment: I also would like to know the answer to the question. As a template it would allow abs to work with your own classes that support the appropriate operators.

Comment: @Columbo And why not?

Comment: It would make it a lot easier to write `&abs<double>` - currently that's a pain.

Comment: @MariusBancila: Comparing a string to an integer would not compile but would admittedly give an unintellegible error message. However, you can add something like `std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<T>, void>`  and you'll get an error like "Candidate template ignored because..." which is very descriptive.

Comment: Also see [Is std::abs(0u) ill-formed?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29750946/1708801)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

See [LWG issue 2192](http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-active.html#2192). Currently, `std::abs(x-y) < 2` fails if `x` and `y` are unsigned. This catches a subtle programming error. With the proposed change, it compiles but does entirely the wrong thing. `abs(3u-4u)` would be much larger than 2, in fact it's `UINT_MAX`.

Comment: @MohitJain `0u - 1u == UINT_MAX`, and `UINT_MAX == 2^(whatever) - 1`.

Comment: That is a great example and issue 2192 is an interesting read.

Comment: Well, `std::abs(3u - 4u)` compiles. See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/abs/.

Comment: Still, I do not get it why the overloads for integral types return a `double` instead of the original integral type.

Comment: @Lingxi: Wrong page? http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/abs/ . Or look at a better site: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/abs

Comment: It's counter-intuitive to me that the overloads for signed integral types are put in `<cstdlib>` other than `<cmath>`. I just thought that all math functions are put int the latter header.

Comment: @Lingxi: That's another issue, [LWG 2294](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-active.html#2294)

Answer (score 11):

This suffers the usual problem of matching everything.

An example of a type for which `abs` makes sense but this implementation does not is `complex<double>`.

Comment: There is an `std::abs` overload for complex numbers that would be found by overload resolution and preferred, since it is more specialized (in terms of partial ordering) than the above.

Comment: @Columbo: it does answer the question why you can't eliminate _all_ current overloads.

Comment: @MSalters Well you could specialise the template for Complex.

Comment: @Columbo: The point isn't that `complex<double>` won't work as is: the point is to demonstrate the definition in the OP can be flat out wrong for reasonable types. Similar user-defined types would fail to compile (or worse, silently compile a *wrong* implementation).

Comment: @Hurkyl I didn't try to criticize your answer anyway, that was more of a side-note - this template and overloads for e.g. `complex` go together quite well :)

Comment: It gets to a point where you can't protect the user from calling functions they don't understand.

Comment: @NeilKirk:That specialization would be a partial specialization (`std::complex<T>` itself is a template) and you cannot partially specialize functions - precisely because you can have overloads.

Comment: @Hurkyl What you said also applies to `std::swap`. It do not think it is a problem.

Comment: @Hurkyl But you do answer why we should live with the overloads :)

Comment: This could be solved [with a little bit of ADL](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/60140/15094) injected into the function.

Comment: But aren't these problems similar for std::less? If you feed it with rubbish you get rubbish.

Answer (score 1):

Because type 'T' can access any data type including char. So what are you expecting if someone will pass a char to the abs function. :)

Comment: The same as for int, except it will only be 8-bits.

Comment: yes @NeilKirk you are correct as c++ will do a ascii value manipulation we will get a result . But that is not a output what an end user want.

Comment: No, C++ won't do an " ASCII"  manipulation. it will without a doubt do a numerical manipulation. The biggest issue in fact would be that `char` may be unsigned, which would give rather unexpected results (!)

Comment: It's common to use char types to hold 8-bit data as, well, there isn't any alternative, at least not in the past. Performing abs on `char` would be of questionable usefulness however, as its signness is implementation defined.